# How to import list from database and make its objects available to select

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

First, I definitely have to apologize for the worst title of the question ever.
I have 3 models in my project: Person, Process, System. It is easy to create a person object. For process I need not only to enter some string data, but also give users possibility to link some of the existing person objects to a new process.
The code for `CreateProcess.cshtml`:

```html
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>


    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="linkedSystems" class="control-label"> Системы </label>
        <input asp-for="linkedSystems" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="linkedSystems" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <datalist id="dataPersons">
        if (Model.Person!= 0)
        {}
        @*@foreach (var item in db)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)}
    }
@foreach (Person item in personNames)
    {
        <option>@item.Name</option>
    }*@

        <option>Denis</option>
        <option>Mike</option>
        <option>Jone</option>
        <option>Spencer</option>
        <option>Jacoby</option>
        <option>Elsa</option>
        <option>Harry</option>
        <option>Andy</option>
    </datalist>
```

As you can see, the code with `DisplayFor` is commented, because I cannot find the appropriate object to link to.
I hope someone had similar problem.

`Person` model:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public int Test { get; set; } // this is not used anywhere, it was created by my colleague for his tests
    public int Age { get; set; } 
}
```

It might be important to see the `Process` Model

```cs
public class Process
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name;
    public List<Systems> linkedSystems;
    public List<Person> linkedPeople;
    public string dataComposition;
    public string monetaryRightsSubjects;
    public string processBasis;   
}
```

Comment: Could you post your controller too, pls?

Comment: You specified linq so does that mean you are using Entity?  Then controller isn't needed.  You need a mapping for your entity model which will automatically be created when you add a data source.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Entity. The main problem of my task is that I have no idea how to use my database and import it to the CreateProcess.cshtml in order to display existing person objects as options to link

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you need to multiselect persons to assing them to process?

Comment: @Adlorem exactly

Comment: Do you have database table relation between process <-> assingedpersons <-> persons

Comment: @Adlorem the thing is, that I have relation process -> assinged people, but while creating a new process there are no person items linked to it yet. I need to import list of all people in the database and make them available to select. The problem is that I cannot import the list from anywhere. I've tried to add using linq, using ApplicationContext, also tried to change void OnGet in cs file for this cshtml

Comment: I don't see in your Process any assigned Persons list. This should be first step.